# Why do I need the on premises Data gateway?

Tags: powerbi, azure-analysis-services, onpremises-gateway

I'm really confused, and a bit lost here.

I have uploaded a data model (Using Visual Studio SSDT) to my Azure Analysis Service.

I have configured my on-prem data gateway - (from Azure & on my laptop where my SQL Server is).

Using power Bi desktop, I can connect to the data model I uploaded using Visual studio by simply providing the Azure Analysis Service server url.

It works.

Why on earth do I need the on-prem data gateway for??

What did I achieve?

I had the impression it was meant to keep my SQL server db and my Azure analysis service model in-sync. But obviously, if I upload using the SSDT tool, I bypass the gateway.

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion that you need to install the gateway?

Comment: i just followed the microsoft instructions on setting up Azure Analysis Services with PowerBI

Comment: Link? If you want help about something, you need to provide more information. I find several Microsoft pages about connecting Azure Analysis Service to Power BI that have no mention of any gateway. So, if you found a document that says you have to install the gateway and you don't understand why, then you may want to point to that document.

Comment: You don't need a gateway to connect to Azure AS, only if it is an on-prem SSAS version

Comment: How do you connect to your datasource? Is the datasource the SQL Server (on your laptop)?